# pip can't find latest versions of a pypi project

Tags: django, installation, virtualenv, pip

I'm trying to install http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-crowdsourcing/1.1.21 using pip. I'm getting

```
$ pip install django-crowdsourcing==1.1.21
Downloading/unpacking django-crowdsourcing==1.1.21
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement django-crowdsourcing==1.1.21 (from versions: )
No distributions matching the version for django-crowdsourcing==1.1.21
```

If I try an upgrade, it only finds version 1.1.19.

```
$ pip install -v --upgrade django-crowdsourcing
Downloading/unpacking django-crowdsourcing
  Using version 1.1.19 (newest of versions: 1.1.19, 1.1.18, 1.1.17, 1.1.16, 1.1.15, 1.1.14, 1.1.13, 1.1.12, 1.1.11, 1.1.10, 1.1.9, 1.1.8, 1.1.7, 1.1.6)
  Downloading django-crowdsourcing-1.1.19.tar.gz (651Kb): 651Kb downloaded
  ...
Successfully installed django-crowdsourcing
```

It looks like django-crowdsourcing version 1.1.21 has some good tags

```
$ hg tags
tip                              289:8796aae85e34
1.1.21                           288:2f39596495a7
1.1.20                           281:fe00699aa3ff
1.1.19                           278:17392ea8ea54
```

and the correct version number in setup.py

```
try:
    from setuptools import setup
except ImportError:
    from distutils.core import setup

import os
readme_file = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                           'README')
long_description = open(readme_file).read()

classifiers = [
    'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
    'Framework :: Django',
    'License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License']


setup(name='django-crowdsourcing',
      version='1.1.21',
      classifiers=classifiers,
      description='Django app for collecting and displaying surveys.',
      long_description=long_description,
      author='Jacob Smullyan, Dave Smith',
      author_email='jsmullyan@gmail.com',
      url='http://code.google.com/p/django-crowdsourcing/',
      packages=['crowdsourcing', 'crowdsourcing.templatetags'],
      license='MIT',
     )
```

PyPi clearly knows about version 1.1.21 since that's what comes up when you go to http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-crowdsourcing/ Why does pip think version 1.1.19 is the latest version?

**Edit**

Sheepishly, I forgot to point out I'm the maintainer. @Matthew Schinckel is right. Here are the two commands I needed, which I found out from a tutorial I didn't see before: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Tutorial

```
$ python setup.py register
$ python setup.py sdist upload
```

Comment: The last Distutils link is broken.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no packaged file at version 1.1.21. There is one at 1.1.19. Tags in hg mean nothing to pip: it will only download a packaged up file.

Perhaps contact the maintainer, and point out there is no file release with the two most recent versions on pypi.